# Get the images straight to the div width

Tags: html, css

I have a image gallery which is not straighting/fullfilling the full width in a row

### html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<figure class="gallery">
    <img src="images/blog_1.png" alt="img">
    <img src="images/blog_1.png" alt="img">
    <img src="images/blog_1.png" alt="img">
    <img src="images/blog_1.png" alt="img">
    <img src="images/blog_1.png" alt="img">
    <img src="images/blog_1.png" alt="img">
</figure>
</div>
```

### css

```
.gallery{
    display:table;
 }
 .gallery img{
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 2px;
     background: transparent;
 }
```

`display:table-cell` is also not working . There is 6 images here

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not quiet sure what's the problem http://jsfiddle.net/hn5ettbo/ .. I just added width and height to img

Comment: i guess may be the problem with image size and bootstrap width col-md-6 try to increase to col-md-10

Comment: it shows but i want the images fill gaps horizontally in a div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tyc7ksL9/ maybe this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.gallery{
    display:table;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .gallery img{
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 2px;
     background: transparent;
    
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<figure class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" />
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood (since you have not mentioned the image size.)

```css
.gallery{
 }
.gallery > div{
    padding:2px;
}
 .gallery img{
     background: transparent;
    width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="gallery row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" alt="img"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" alt="img"/>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Below css

```
    .gallery{
    display:table;
    margin:0;
      }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hn5ettbo/2/)